# Boot hangs in a live USB over a Toshiba Qosimo X75

Tags: system-installation

I just purchased a Toshiba Qosimo X75-A7298 laptop and want to install Ubuntu on it (don't particularly care which version).  I tried both V12.04LTS and 13.10.  The boot process hangs almost immediately after I choose to "Try Ubuntu without installing".  I turned off "secure boot" and changed the boot mode from "UEFI" to "CSM" with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing the video problem before switching modes.
For UEFI machines (with a black screen grub (grub-efi)  without any
function key options, like the older grub-pc, edit the grub menu and add
the below options on the "linux" line, then boot with F10 or ctrl-X.

Options for Video problems:

```
nomodeset
acpi=0
acpi_osi=linux
acpi_backlight=vendor
noalpic
i915.i915_enable_rc6=1
video=1280x1024-24@60
video=VGA-1:1280x1024-24@60
```

To allow Nvidia hybrid machines to boot.

```
nouveau.blacklist=1
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only gets me part way.  I tried to boot the trial run, and it fails to start X.  It boots to a command prompt, with no message as to why.  Any thoughts?

Comment: search this site for "bumblebee". Might help your hybrid? video problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the Toshiba Qosmio X75-A7298. Here's where I got the iso:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Basically, I just burn the ISO called "trusty-desktop-amd64.iso" to a DVD.

I pressed F2 a few times, right after turning on the Toshiba Qosmio X75-A7298. That took me to the bios and I too disabled secure boot and changed the boot mode from "UEFI" to "CSM" in the "Advanced" section of the bios.

After saving these changes and rebooting, this time I held down the "c" key so that it would know to boot from the dvd I burned.

The only issue I'm now having is I can't figure out how to adjust the screen brightness:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1295141

Oh, and by the way. This laptop runs Ubuntu 14.04 blazingly fast.